# How to get the route with namespace by route name in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a route as following

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/entry', 'namespace' => 'acme'], function() {

    Route::get('add', [
        'uses' => 'EntriesController@add',
        'as' => 'entry.add'
    ]);

});
```

How to get a complete route ('acme\EntriesController@add') if somewhere in my code I only know the route name?
Something like

```
$route = Route::getRoute('entry.add');
```

Comment: What exactly do you wanna get? The URL of that route or the class and and action name as string?

Comment: I want to get the namespace and controller class and action like `acme\EntriesController@add`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, here's how you get a route object by it's name:

```
$route = Route::getRoutes()->getByName('route.name');
```

And the route object has the method `getActionName()`, so:

```
echo Route::getRoutes()->getByName('entry.add')->getActionName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I have created global functions for my use.

For Example:

```
$routes = getRouteByName('role.add.form');
```

it will return response like below:

```
Array
(
[uri] => roles/addrole
[name] => role.add.form
[prefix] => 
[action] => Array
    (
        [middleware] => Array
            (
                [0] => web
            )

        [domain] => admin.local.com
        [uses] => App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AccessControlController@create
        [controller] => App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AccessControlController@create
        [namespace] => App\Http\Controllers\Admin
        [prefix] => 
        [where] => Array
            (
            )

        [as] => role.add.form
    )

[action_method] => create
[action_name] => App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AccessControlController@create
[domain] => admin.local.com
)
```

Below are the functions created globally:

```
if(!function_exists('getRoutes')){

function getRoutes(){

    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

    $routes = [];
    foreach ($routeCollection as $route) {
        $routes[] = [
            'uri' => $route->uri,
            'name' => $route->getName(),
            'prefix' => $route->getPrefix(),
            'action_method' => $route->getActionMethod(),
            'action_name' => $route->getActionName(),
        ];
    }

    return $routes;
}
}

/**
 * @param string $name pass route name as parameter
 * @param string $param pass the element from the route instance
 * @return return all data of route by default or value when second parameter passed
 *          [uri,name,prefix,action_method,action_name]
 * **/
if(!function_exists('getRouteByName')){

function getRouteByName($name,$param = null){

    $route = Route::getRoutes()->getByName($name);
    $route_data = [
        'uri' => $route->uri,
        'name' => $route->getName(),
        'prefix' => $route->getPrefix(),
        'action' => $route->getAction(),
        'action_method' => $route->getActionMethod(),
        'action_name' => $route->getActionName(),
        'domain' => $route->getDomain(),
    ];

    if(!empty($param)){
        return $route_data[$param];
    }
    else{
        return $route_data;
    }
}
}
```